# How to extract data from this JSON?

Tags: java, json

I have the following JSON Array as a string like this,

```
String output = "[{\"Symbol\":\"AMZN\",\"Name\":\"Amazon.com Inc\",\"Exchange\":\"NASDAQ\"},{\"Symbol\":\"VXAZN\",\"Name\":\"CBOE Amazon VIX Index\",\"Exchange\":\"Market Data Express\"}]";
```

I want to parse it and make a string array like this,

```
array = {"AMZN Amazon.com Inc NASDAQ", "VXAZN CBOE Amazon VIX Index Market Data Express"};
```

I came up with the following code to parse the string into a JSON Array using the `json-simple-1.1.1.jar` library,

```
import org.json.simple.*;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;


public class RESTclient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            String output = "[{\"Symbol\":\"AMZN\",\"Name\":\"Amazon.com Inc\",\"Exchange\":\"NASDAQ\"},{\"Symbol\":\"VXAZN\",\"Name\":\"CBOE Amazon VIX Index\",\"Exchange\":\"Market Data Express\"}]";

            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

            JSONArray jsonArray = null;

            try {
                jsonArray = (JSONArray) parser.parse(output);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println(jsonArray);
        }
}
```

This gives me the following **OUTPUT**,

```
[{"Name":"Amazon.com Inc","Exchange":"NASDAQ","Symbol":"AMZN"},{"Name":"CBOE Amazon VIX Index","Exchange":"Market Data Express","Symbol":"VXAZN"}]
```

Now after this, is there an elegant way to achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write extra code.

```
ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Iterator iterator = jsonArray.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    JSONObject map = (JSONObject)iterator.next();
    stringArray.add(map.get("Symbol")+" "+map.get("Name")+" "+map.get("Exchange"));
}
//stringArray is want you want
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Jackson like,

```
    private ObjectMapper    mapper  = new ObjectMapper();
    String[] outputArray = mapper.readValue(jsonString, String[].class);
```